# Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters - MySQLi

Tags: mysqli, prepared-statement

Okay guys, so I'm trying to use the following code to update some values, for a game server database.

```
$db1 = "versound_store";

//connection to the database

$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $sqluser, $sqlpass, $db1);


   if( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE vxp_users SET tokens =?, xp =?, level =? WHERE steamid ='?'"))
   {
   $stmt->bind_param('isss', $tokens, $xp, $level, $steamid00);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->close() or trigger_error($db->error);
   }
   else {
   printf("Prep statment failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
   }
$mysqli->close();
$db2 = "versound_stats";
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $sqluser, $sqlpass, $db2);
   if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ttt_stats SET roundsplayed =?, playtime =? WHERE steamid ='?'"))
   {
   $stmt->bind_param('iis', $roundsplayed, $totalplaytime, $steamid00);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->close() or trigger_error($db->error);
   }
   else {
   printf("Prep statment failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
   }
$mysqli->close();
```

But of course, for both queries I get `Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement on line 64`.

$tokens is a number usually between -50 and 10000.

$xp is a number usually between -100 and 269000.

$level is a number usually between 1 and 50.

$roundsplayed is a number above 0.

$totalplaytime is a number usually between 1 and 1000000.

$steamid00 is a string formatted like STEAM_0:1:23456789.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

culprit

```
WHERE steamid ='?'"
```

dont use the quotes

```
WHERE steamid =?"
```